# Reinsertar un número si se ha repetido el último

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un mini ejercicio donde he de introducir 6 números (array) entre 1-49, si se repiten los números volver a pedirlo. Una vez insertado los 6 números, el ordenador generará 6 números aleatorios sin repetir y comprobará cuantos aciertos han habido. Mi duda principal es que logro hacerlo todo excepto lo de pedir nuevamente un número si el último que he insertado ya se halla en el array:

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] loteria = new int[6];
    int[] loteria2 = new int[6];
    int[] ran = new int[6];
    int[] ran2 = new int[6];
    int acerts = 0;
    int contenidor = 0;
    int ra = 0;
    System.out.println("Digues els numeros de la loteria");
    for (int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
        loteria[i] = entrada.nextInt();
        boolean encontrado = false;
        while ((encontrado) && (contenidor < loteria2.length)) {
            if (loteria2[contenidor] == loteria[i]) {
                encontrado = true;

            }
            contenidor++;
            if (encontrado) {
                System.out.println(loteria[i] + " repetido. Insertar otro: ");
                loteria[i] = entrada.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
        ran[i] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;

    }
    System.out.println("Numeros introduits: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(loteria[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Combinació ganadora:");
    for (int i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(ran[i] + " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ran.length; j++) {
            if (loteria[i] == ran[j]) {
                acerts++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Aciertos: " + acerts);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica de los re-intentos está errada. Si te fijas en el código, inicializas la variable `encontrado` en false y luego tienes esto:

```
while ((encontrado) && (contenidor < loteria2.length)) {
```

Dado que `encontrado` es `false`, esa expresión siempre evaluará a `false` y por tanto el código que está dentro del `while` no se ejecuta.

Sugiero cambiar la implementación por un `do/while`, que nos garantiza que el código se ejecutará al menos una vez. Evaluamos la condición al final y si esta se cumple, repetimos el código en un ciclo hasta que el número introducido sea satisfactorio.

Por lo mismo, sugiero también *pedir* el dato al usuario dentro del mismo ciclo. De esa manera nos aseguramos a pedirlo tantas veces como sea posible.

En resumen, quedaría algo así:

```
// ciclo principal para recorrer todas las posiciones.
for (int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
    boolean encontrado;
    // ciclo secundario para pedir una posición y asegurarse que no esté duplicada
    do {
      encontrado = false;
      loteria[i] = entrada.nextInt();
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (loteria[j] == loteria[i]) {
          encontrado = true;
          System.out.println(loteria[i] + " repetido. Insertar otro: ");
        }
      }
    } while (encontrado);
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta Jachguate, el código que me proporcionas es fácil de entender y poner en práctica).

Answer (score 1):

**EDITADO**

quite las imagenes, he trado de explicar en detalle cada parte del codigo..
si nada mas que decir el codigo deberia estar asi:

```
private static final int maxNum = 6;

public static void main(final String[] args)
{

    final int[] numUser = new int[maxNum];//verctor de numeros del usiario
    final int[] numRan = new int[maxNum];//verctor de numenos random

    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//entra del usuario

    //si el index(variable 'i') en igual quel numero maximo ya de tienen todos los numeros y termina el bucle
    for(int i = 0; i<maxNum;)
    {//pedir al usuario que ingrese numeros hasta que se complete.
        System.out.print("ingresa un numero entre 1 y 49: ");
        final int num = sc.nextInt();

        //si el numero es menor que 1, no esta en el rango y no es valido.
        if(num<1)continue;//regresara a comienzo del bucle

        //si el numero es mayor que 49, no esta en el rango y no es valido.
        if(num>49)continue;//regresara a comienzo del bucle

        //aqui miramos si el nuevo numero que estaba en el array.
        /**
         hay que notar que esta en positivo(contains) y no en negativo(noContains)
         ya que para obtener el negativo se usa el operador not(!) antes..
         **/
        if(!contains(numUser,num))
        {
            numUser[i]=num;//establecemos el valor en el index actual.

            i=i+1;//pasamos al siguiente index.
            //i++; <- eso es quivalente a lo de arriba.
        }

        //fin de buble
        //si el numero ya era repetido no se pasa al sigiente index.
    }

    //para los numero random se hace lo mismo que el bucle anterior..

    for(int i = 0; i<maxNum;)
    {
        //lo unico que cambia es quien define el numero, antes era el usuario..


        //ahora 'a' tiene un numero aliatorio entre 0 y 1;
        //pero nunca 0 o 1
        final double a = Math.random();

        //ahora 'b' tiene un numero aliatorio entre 0 y 49;
        //pero nunca 0 o 49
        final double b = a*49;

        //redondiamos hacia abajo, ejemplo1: 1.3 -> 1 ... ejemplo2: 1.9 -> 1
        // ahora 'c' tiene un numero entero entre 0 y 48, por que redondiamos hacia abajo.
        final double c = Math.floor(b);

        //ahora si, 'd' tiene un numero entre 1 y 49, ya que cualfuere el valor se aumento en 1.
        final double d = c+1;

        //pasamos 'd' a entero...
        final int num = (int)d;
        //todo esto fue para explicar paso a paso, esto se miraria asi:..
        //final int num = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*49)+1;

        //todo sigue igual que al usuario.
        /***/
        if(num<1)continue;

        if(num>49)continue;

        if(!contains(numRan,num))
        {
            numRan[i]=num;
            i=i+1;
        }
    }

    for(int userNum: numUser)//interamos sobre todos los numero
    {
        if(contains(numRan,userNum))//preguntamos con cada numero de usuaril si esta en la lista de los random
        {
            //damos el mensaje
            System.out.println("El numero: "+userNum+"esta en las dos listas.");
        }
    }

    //ahora imprimiremos los las dos listas

    System.out.println("Numeros del usuario:");
    printArray(numUser);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Numeros Ramdom:");
    printArray(numRan);
}

private static void printArray(int[] array)
{
    for(int i: array)//iteramos sobre el array de numeros..
    {
        System.out.println(i);//imprimimos si valor
    }
}

//Este metodo dice si el numero(num) esta en el vector(nums)
private static boolean contains(final int[] nums,final int num)
{
    for(int i: nums)//iteramos sobre el vector
    {
        if(i==num)//si el numero esta el vector retornara verdadero y se termina el metodo.
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;//si la itercion se termina y no hay valores iguales retornamos falso.
}
```

Comment: Se agradece las intenciones de ayudar, pero favor no colocar capturas del codigo. mejor copia y pegalo como texto para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad. De paso leete [answer].

Comment: Si... Es que me da un error que me dice que el comentario tiene código y no se cómo ponerlo... Me ayudas?

Comment: No lo agregres como comentario, [edit] la respuesta y actualizala. De paso te dejo los siguientes enlace [answer] y [Ayuda de Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) para que mejores las publicaciones y sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: No hace falta que incluyas el texto "EDITADO" ya que ne la parte inferior de la respuesta se encuentra un enlace que indica que ha sido indica y lleva al historial de revisiones.

Comment: no lo sabia, gracias.